# Plot high price of specific 5-minute bar at certain time of each day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to plot the high price of the 5-minute bar at 2045hrs of each day in pinescript.

Let me clarify with an example.

Suppose today is 28 June. At 2045hrs on 28June, a horizontal line at high price of the 5-minute bar at 2045hrs will be plotted and remains at this value until the next day. On the next day 29 June, the horizontal line will shift to the high price of the 5-minute bar at 2045hrs on 29June. The same process repeats for each day.

I am using pinescript v5

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the [Pine Script `request.security()` function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-security) is used to request data from other contexts than the chart's. In particular, from other [timeframes](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html#pagetimeframes).
But in your case, you can create a script designed to be applied directly to a 5-minute chart. The script operates on the 5-minute timeframe and captures the high price of the 5-minute bar at 20:45 each day.

Combine that with [plot()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Plots.html?highlight=plot), and you can try, daily:

```
//@version=5
indicator("20:45 High Price Plotter", overlay=true, shorttitle="HP@2045")

var float highPriceAt2045 = na

if (hour == 20) and (minute == 45)
    highPriceAt2045 := high

plot(highPriceAt2045[1], color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="High Price at 20:45", trackprice=true)
```

This script should be applied to a 5-minute chart in [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/). It checks if the current 5-minute bar is at 20:45, and if so, captures the high price of that bar and plots it as a horizontal line. The line remains at this value until 20:45 the next day, at which point it will update to the new high price of that day's 20:45 bar.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out your answer. This is the first time I have someone with more than 1m points answer my question. I guess you're the genius among all geniuses on Stackoverflow. Lol.

Comment: @user3848207 Not a genius ;) It is best to test the answer *before* accepting it: don't hesitate to edit your question with your code and what is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question for future reference since it's more suitable for my needs. The answer is based on the answer from @Vonc which has been marked as the right answer.

```
var float highPriceAt2045 = na

if ( hour(time, timezone="Asia/Singapore") == 20 and minute(time, timezone="Asia/Singapore") == 45)
    highPriceAt2045 := high

plot(highPriceAt2045[1], color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="High Price at 20:45", trackprice=true)
```

The main difference is I added local timezone.

Comment: Good catch, well done.